# Copy values from one XMP tag to another XMP tag

Tags: metadata, exiftool, xmp

I have a lot of images (JPG) with some metadata.
I'm interested in these three tags, for example, from one of the images:

> [XMP]           FlightPitchDegree               : 0.734793
> [XMP]           FlightRollDegree                : -1.024403
> [XMP]           FlightYawDegree                 : 192.286436

I need to copy these values for each image to the next tags:

> Xmp.Camera.Pitch
> Xmp.Camera.Roll
> Xmp.Camera.Yaw

Mostly for tag editing, I'm using ExifTool, but I can't find commands for copying values between tags inside one file.
I'll be very appreciative of any recommendation.

Best,
Andriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy from one tag to another you would use the redirection feature of the [`-TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT).  Basically it would be
`exiftool "-TARGETTAG<SOURCETAG" file.xmp`

You have the names of the SourceTags (`FlightPitchDegree`/`FlightRollDegree`/`FlightYawDegree`), you just need to figure out the exiftool names of your target tags.  I can find `CameraPitch`/`CameraYaw`/`CameraRoll` tags on the [DJI Tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/DJI.html), but those are not XMP tags.  The only other place I can find tags with similar names are part of the XMP-Camera group, which are not built into exiftool and you would have to download the [pix4d.config file](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/master/config_files/pix4d.config) and use the [`-Config` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#config-CFGFILE) to include those definitions.

```
exiftool -config /path/to/pix4d.config "-XMP:Pitch< FlightPitchDegree" "-XMP:Yaw<FlightYawDegree" "-XMP:Roll< FlightRollDegree" file.xmp
```

The `-config` option must be the very first option in the command in order to load the definitions.